# I keep getting an [$injector:modulerr] in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm going over my JS as best I can, but I cannot seem to find any glaring issues. I get the following:
 `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module careApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'careApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

I've ensured that I'm using the correct modules and dependencies as well. Nothing appears to be mispelled or out of place.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the `$routeProvider` section in my JS...

```
'use strict';

(function() {

  var AppCtrl;
  AppCtrl = function() {
    function AppCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.list = [{
        label: 'Main Menu',
        icon: 'fa fa-home fa-fw 4x',
        link: '#/homePage',
        move: function() {
          console.log("HOME");
        }
      }, {
        label: 'Patient',
        icon: 'fa fa-user fa-fw 4x',
        link: '#/pCredential',
        move: function() {
          console.log("PATIENT");
        }
      }, {
        label: 'Technician',
        icon: 'fa fa-user-md fa-fw 4x',
        link: '#/tLogin',
        move: function() {
          console.log("TECHNICIAN");
        }
      }, {
        label: 'Administrator',
        icon: 'fa fa-cogs fa-fw 4x',
        link: '#/aLogin',
        move: function() {
          console.log("ADMINISTRATOR");
        }
      }];
    }
    return AppCtrl;
  }();
  // Declare app level module which depends on views and components
  angular.module('careApp', [
      'ngRoute',
      'ngMaterial',
      'ngAria',
      'ngAnimate'
    ])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('#/homePage' {
          template: '<p>WELCOME HOME!</p>'
        }).
      when('#/pCredential' {
        template: '<p>INSERT CREDENTIALS INTO NODE.</p>'
      }).
      when('#/tLogin' {
        template: '<p>PLEASE LOGIN TO THE TECHNICIAN PAGE.</p><p>GET CREDENTIALS FROM OWNER.</p>'
      }).
      when('#/aLogin' {
        template: '<p>ADMINISTRATOR ACCESS.</p>'
      })

      //load default page on page refresh
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/appLaunch'
      });
    }])

  .controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', AppCtrl]);

}());
```

**Current Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Miega/mowwckze/3/**

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you ever want to minimize this, I suggest you use [inline array notation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation). If you don't do this, `$scope` as the parameter to your controller function will be minified and the app won't be able to determine that you want it as a dependency, leading to you into _another_ kind of injection error. Joy Clay's answer is good, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing commas after the first parameter in all of your `.when` route definitions.

```
$routeProvider
  .when('#/homePage', {
    template: '<p>WELCOME HOME!</p>'
  }).
  when('#/pCredential', {
    template: '<p>INSERT CREDENTIALS INTO NODE.</p>'
  }).
  when('#/tLogin', {
    template: '<p>PLEASE LOGIN TO THE TECHNICIAN PAGE.</p><p>GET CREDENTIALS FROM OWNER.</p>'
  }).
  when('#/aLogin', {
    template: '<p>ADMINISTRATOR ACCESS.</p>'
  })
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks!

Comment: Easy mistake to make!